# Microdata and Meta tags

Tags: html, metadata, meta

Can `meta` tags be used within HTML body?
I am using [microdata](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/176035) in my website. The examples from [schema.org](http://schema.org) uses a `meta` to provide more information about an item without rendering the `worstRating` to the user. See example.

My concern is how valid is it to use a `meta` tag in the HTML body?
Web Essentials shows the error:

> Element 'meta' cannot be nested inside element 'div'

Is something which is valid for HTML 5?

**Example** - [link](http://schema.org/Product).

```
<div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
  <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="1">
  <span itemprop="ratingValue">1</span>/
  <span itemprop="bestRating">5</span>stars
</div>
```